# Paypal Sandbox Credit Card in Use Error Message

Tags: paypal, sandbox, credit-card

Within Paypal Sandbox, when I try to add a credit card to the buyers account, I keep getting the error message "That card number is already assigned to another PayPal account."  I don't get it, since Paypal just generated the number for me when I made the test account.  What am I not getting here?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use another fake-but-valid credit card number. The ones of PP_MTS_Chad does not work for me but there are services out there - for example http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/ - which can help you to generate a new fake-but-valid credit card number.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing the page and generating a different credit card number?  If that doesn't work, below are some test Visa credit card numbers that should work.

Visa
4024007100084663
4532097039922088
4684431180691661
4532281047529784
4485709869935124
4532455118197917
4532751738631248
4024007151460556
4485191830561711
4024007120680144

MasterCard
5298938631492858
5366456971629085
5280019641034996
5332799760390380
5457222336826489
5367034163101350
5359283541706691
5489595916141912
5140323874680289
5246932992053568